# Making my own custom Ubuntu

Tags: customization, custom-distributions

I was wondering, is it possible to make my own customized version of Linux based on Ubuntu 10.10 ?

I am thinking of calling it something different but I was wondering besides making a custom Live CD I am talking about an Linux that people can install on there computers using Ubuntu installation method.

I want to base it on something other than GNOME but be able to install it latter on.

Thanks in advance,

Benny

Comment: sure there is livecd dociumentation, however, you'll need lots of free time , to learn all that is needed to make it work, and then customize it https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD or you can download Ubuntu Customization Kit which makes eveything much easier

Comment: @Uri Herrera I want to make an Ubuntu based os that it but called an different thing and peple can install it.

Comment: well that's not easy a task from what i know, i've been trying to make my own too, and so far i've only managed to change the theme and some icons ...

Comment: as i said UCK it's by far the easiest more user-friendly option, there is also remastersys, and reconstructor, but ofcourse  it's not as simple as checking some options on a menu

, sorry for the other link, it's actually this one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could, but it would be a lot of work.

If you're not a fan of Gnome, have you tried taking a look at the other distributions based on Ubuntu?

- [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)
- [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/)
- [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)
- All the others can be viewed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives)

Comment: Taylor yes I have and now I want to make my own Ubuntu can you provide a link

Comment: here is one if you're interested http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/2859/remastersys-guide-create-your-own-ubuntubased-distro/ , i haven't tried any of the instructions there as it was commented on a question i made 'bout this exact subject and haven't tested if it works