# How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?

Tags: system-installation, custom-distributions

I would like to customize Ubuntu live CD by installing some additional packages. I have followed  [the Ubuntu help wiki guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide clear instructions?

I'm not keen to use Remastersys; I'd prefer a manual way.

#### Customization

**Packages that I want to install:**

- Thunderbird
- Samba
- SSH

**Changes that I need:**

- Remove Games menu from the Application menu
- Firefox shortcut on Desktop
- Radiance as the default Theme
- Different default Ubuntu Wallpaper

#### Configuration file changes

- I want the panel to be placed at the bottom
- I want to paste my Samba configuration file instead of default Samba configuration
- I have few Firefox shortcuts and folders I would like to show that in Desktop
- Also it will be nice if you say me how to change the icon sets

#### Recent Updates

- I have customized Ubuntu 10.10 with Firefox shortcuts and few folders on desktops. Everything went smooth. But the installer gets crashes after choosing the timezone. How do i fix this issue?
- Also setting wallpaper affects the login screen. The wallpaper which I set is displayed on the login screen also. I just want the default one for the login screen.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/83617/62483

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about an End of Standard Support or End of Life Release. This question was written concerning 11.04. Most of the answers use outdated, obsolete, unsupported apps with broken links, such as Remastersys. None of the answers with high reputation are of any use to a user in the modern world. It may be a good history lesson but that is not users are looking for.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

### For recent versions of Ubuntu, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307835/124466).

**Note:** The [Ubuntu Builder project has been discontinued](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder/+announcement/12508).

##Creating a custom 12.04 CD with Gnome-Classic using Ubuntu-Builder
(for now, this is specific to Karthik's needs; I will update answer later with more general/Unity-specific stuff)

###1. Get Ubuntu Builder and your source ISO

[Ubuntu Builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder) automates many of the preliminary steps that had to be done by hand (mount ISO, extract squashfs, create chroot, etc.)  It gives you Synaptic and a "graphical" chroot as well (Unity UI).

Add the PPA to install Ubuntu Builder:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kamilion/ubuntu-builder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder
```

Also download the Ubuntu Desktop ISO you're planning to work with.

###2. Ubuntu Builder Basics

- Start Ubuntu Builder from the Launcher. I recommend you set all three fields to "Ubuntu" (like the actual LiveCD), because setting custom fields led to Software Center crashing. When you install, you can choose your own username, machine name, etc. as always.

  [image]
- Load your ISO; I loaded the 64-bit with the *Local Disk* option, although Ubuntu Builder should be able to download the ISO if you want it to.
- The buttons on the right are self-explanatory. `Console` gives you a CLI chroot, while `Desktop` gives you a [graphical one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGiqY.png), i.e. a LiveCD session itself (this one may take a while to load). Note that the `Select DE/WM` does an incomplete job sometimes, so it's better to install via *apt-get*/Synaptic.

###3. Updating, adding Gnome Classic and other package management

> **Note:** All this can also be done from Synaptic if you are more comfortable with that.

- You can edit the `sources.list` with the button (or via the console) to add your own mirrors, ppas, etc.

Let's start with:

- Remove the games

  ```
  apt-get remove --purge aisleriot gnome-games-data gnomine mahjongg -y
  ```
- Do a general update and dist-upgrade to the latest stuff (optional, but recommended since the Gnome-classic and other packages you add will be the latest versions) -- on 12.04, this step also installs Thunderbird and the core Samba components. It will also save time on the actual install.

  ```
  apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Install Gnome Classic (`gnome-shell` to pull in indicators, etc.), Samba and SSH:

  ```
  apt-get install gnome-shell samba ssh
  ```

###4. Customization 1: Files, configs and removing the top-panel

> **Note:** All commands must be run from the chrooted console of Ubuntu Builder *unless otherwise noted* (usually when copying files from your own system). The absolute path of the chroot is `/home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem`

1. Replace Samba configuration file (from your own system terminal, i.e. outside chroot!)

```
sudo cp /path/to/mysmb.conf /home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

2. Put Firefox shortcut on desktop:

```
mkdir -p /etc/skel/Desktop && cd /etc/skel/Desktop
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop .
chmod +x firefox.desktop
```

2. Copy custom shortcuts and folders to Desktop (from outside chroot!)

   ```
   sudo cp -r /path/to/mydesktopitems/ /home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem/etc/skel/Desktop/
   ```
3. Set `gnome-classic` as the default shell:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-classic
```

4. Remove the top Gnome-Classic panel and move top-items to the bottom-panel:

- Open the default panel layout:

  ```
  nano /usr/share/gnome-panel/panel-default-layout.layout
  ```
- Delete the top-panel, by removing lines 1-4:

  ```
  [Toplevel top-panel]
  ```

expand=true
orientation=top
size=24

- Move the Start Menu to the bottom left by modifying the **bolded** value for the *italicized* parameter as below:

[Object menu-bar]
object-iid=PanelInternalFactory::MenuBar
*toplevel-id*=**bottom-panel**
pack-index=0

- Move the indicators to the bottom right, just to the left of the Workspace Switcher, by modifying the **bolded** value for the *italicized* parameters as below:

[Object indicators]
object-iid=IndicatorAppletCompleteFactory::IndicatorAppletComplete
*toplevel-id*=**bottom-panel**
pack-type=end
*pack-index*=**1**

- Remove the "Show Desktop" button from the bottom left; I prefer the Start Menu to be the first thing there, you can leave it or move it to the bottom right, etc. Delete these lines:

[Object show-desktop]
object-iid=WnckletFactory::ShowDesktopApplet
toplevel-id=bottom-panel
pack-index=0

- Save and exit.

###5. Customization 2: Backgrounds and Themes

> Note: `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` contains most of the default background/theme settings; I found it easier to directly modify those for a LiveCD instead of having to deal [complicated stuff](https://askubuntu.com/a/64002/58612) just to, for example, prevent the login screen background from being the same as the desktop background.

1. Disable the login screen *(lightdm)* from "copying" the desktop background and other changes:

- Open `nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml`
- You can change the login background from the default here if you want:

<key name="**background**" type="s">
<default>**'/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'**</default>

- Disable "copying" the desktop background by setting this to `false`:

  ```
   <key name="draw-user-backgrounds" type="b">
    <default>false</default>
  ```

- Set the login theme to Radiance:

```
          <key name="theme-name" type="s">
      <default>'Radiance'</default>
```

2. Change the default wallpaper; here, we'll set it to the included ["Tie My Boat"](http://dev.minus.com/lbs8HDuEp1ecJj) (`/usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_García.jpg`):

- Open `nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_gsettings-desktop-schemas.gschema.override`, and change the below line to the path for your file:

picture-uri='file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'

3. Change the theme to *Radiance*

- Open Ubuntu's theme override file ``nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ubuntu-artwork.gschema.override`, and change the *Ambiance* below to *Radiance*:

[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
gtk-theme="**Ambiance**"
...
[org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences]
theme="**Ambiance**"

4. **Important: Compile the modified schemas!**

- Now that we're done customizing, compile the modified schemas with:

  ```
  glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
  ```

###6. Build, test and install!

- Press the `Build` button in Ubuntu Builder to begin building the custom Live-CD ISO. UB automatically handles the cleanup, etc. that previously had to be done manually.

  [image]
- The ISO can be found in `/home/ubuntu-builder`; you can test it using the built-in QEMU, or in another virtual machine.
- My finished CD size was 778 MB (after removing the old `.23` kernel), with Unity and Gnome 3D still available if the user wishes to, so that's pretty good for a customization! :)

**The following should result:**

1. After bootup, you get the "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" option:

[image]

2. Clicking "Try" gets us our custom desktop!

[image]

3. And logging out (login with `ubuntu`, blank password) shows that the login wallpaper is kept at the default:

[image]

4. Installer does not crash upon Timezone selection:

[image]

5. Select username, etc. for install:

[image]

6. Installed login screen:

[image]

7. Installed desktop:

[image]

Comment: How to update/install a package which requires system-restart (for example kernel or dbus)? When I try to update it installs; but in gui-mode, session-indicator turns red & says `restart to complete the update`.

Comment: How do I replace the Ubuntu artwork with my own artwork ?

Comment: This one doesn't work. I dont know why. I am not sure whether this happens to me alone. When I run it inside a virtualbox, it shows a popu saying that "/casper/vmlinuz.efi: file not found". How to correct this? http://s24.postimg.org/jbez8svx1/Untitled.png

Comment: @izx Can you please tell me, how to set working directory for ubuntu-builder? It is creating directory in /home/ubuntu-builder. I run it with root access.

Comment: Just to clarify, doing this not only changes the live session but also the default set of packages that will be installed, correct?

Comment: This project is discontinued. The PPA does not work, and the website has no download links. I suggest to add this info at the beginning of your answer to help others arriving here not wasting his time.

Comment: Sadly now, if you try to install this, it'll crash when you open a drop-down menu in 16.04...

Comment: Ubuntu Builder was discontinued in 2014; Ubuntu Customization Kit installs but doesn't work and was discontinued in 2015; System Imager was discontinued in 2016. This answer really needs to be updated. Is there an offiically supported method in 2019?

Answer (score 123):

## Creating your own Custom Live CD - the manual way.

### 1. Preparations

- First you download the [Live CD ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). While it is downloading install some software that is needed for rebuilding: `sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools schroot`

  [Squashfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/squashfs-tools) [image: Install squashfs-tools] is a compressed read-only filesystem for Linux.

  [schroot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/schroot) [image: Install schroot] allows users to execute commands or interactive shells in different chroots.
- Mount the Live CD:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/livecd
  sudo mount -o loop ~/Downloads/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso /tmp/livecd
  ```

  If you use another ISO or another location for your download please adjust accordingly.
- Create a working area and copy contents over to the working area:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/livecd/cd
  rsync --exclude=/casper/filesystem.squashfs -a /tmp/livecd/ ~/livecd/cd
  mkdir ~/livecd/squashfs  ~/livecd/custom
  sudo modprobe squashfs
  sudo mount -t squashfs -o loop /tmp/livecd/casper/filesystem.squashfs ~/livecd/squashfs/
  sudo cp -a ~/livecd/squashfs/* ~/livecd/custom
  ```
- If you get an error like this while doing modprobe:

  ```
  sudo modprobe squashfs 
  WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, 
  all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/
  ```

  move the modprobe.conf `mv /etc/modprobe.conf /etc/modprobe.conf.OLD` and try again!
- Network access:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/hosts ~/livecd/custom/etc/
  ```
- Create a pseudo filesystem:

  ```
  sudo chroot ~/livecd/custom /bin/bash -l
  mount -t proc none /proc/
  mount -t sysfs none /sys/
  ```

### 2. Customizing

- You can get a list of all packages with 
  `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package}\n' | less`
- You can remove games with `apt-get remove --purge gnome-games`
- Update your sources with`sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Comment out lines you do not want and uncomment the ones you do want, add in PPAs if you want and then you need to update with `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`
- Adding packages like thunderbird, Samba, Samba system config and SSH is done the same way as you would normally install from command line. So `sudo apt-get install thunderbird samba system-config-samba ssh` will add those.
- If you've manually downloaded the package from you can install it with `sudo dpkg -i {file_name}.deb`

  - You can check Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic or the [packages website](http://packages.ubuntu.com) for the names if more need to be installed.
  - You might consider adding (wireless) network utilities.
  - You will quickly run over 800 Mb; if you do you either remove more packages to get under 800 or you need to use a DVD when burning. Removing libre office will free up you 33+ Mb if you do not need it.
- To create an AskUbuntu shortcut on the desktop:

  ```
  mkdir -p /etc/skel/Desktop && printf '[Desktop Entry]\nVersion=1.0\nName=Ask Ubuntu\nComment=Ask Questions About Ubuntu\nGenericName=Question and Answers\nExec=xdg-open http://askubuntu.com\nTerminal=false\nX-MultipleArgs=false\nType=Application\nIcon=firefox\nCategories=Internet;\n' > /etc/skel/Desktop/askubuntu.desktop && chmod a+x /etc/skel/Desktop/askubuntu.desktop
  ```

  You can add more of these (skip the mkdir part) by editing the URL to something else.
  <sub>Courtesy of dv3500ea</sub>
- Changing settings inside gconf-editor.

  You can change any gconf option if you know what the path is of that option and the value you want it to be (and the type of the value of course).

  [image]

  Changing the wallpaper is done with the path I pointed arrows to: `/desktop/gnome/background/`, it is a string value and it uses `picture_filename` as an option. The value it currently holds on my desktop is `/discworld2/Downloads/fantasticwall_2.jpg`. The background itself should be copied into `/usr/share/backgrounds/`. Make sure to set permissions and owner.

  Examples:

  - To change the wallpaper (change the filename in the 1st command to your own image) to this image and to change the theme to Radiance you can use this information to create commands to set this for your live cd:

    ```
    gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t string /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename  /discworld2/Downloads/fantasticwall_2.jpg

    gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t string /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme Radiance
    ```

    <sub>Courtesy of dv3500ea</sub>
  - Enable remote desktop:

    ```
    gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
    ```

    Settings for icons, panels etc are all done by adding a command like this.
  - Alternatively you can edit `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml` (or when you are down save this file for future usage). All the configuration settings done through gconftool-2 are stored in this file.
- Change the default timezone used by the live cd

  ```
  dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
  ```
- Change locale setting to english (of course change it to what you want)

  ```
  locale-gen en
  update-locale LANG=en LANGUAGE=en LC_ALL=en
  ```
- Configure configuration files.

  If you want to have a custom configuration file for a certain package you can do this in several ways.

  The difficult (but most logical) way would be to either find the package, change the configuration file and repackage it or to find the source files, figure out where they store their dummy config file and change that and then rebuild the package.

  - Of course this only works if the default configuration file is included in the source package. Many packages auto-generate their config files in the {packagename}.postinst script so it would make it rather difficult to get this done.

    The easiest way would be to create a script and copy your current config to `/etc/skel` so they get added to your desktop (similar to adding firefox shortcuts as explained above) and after installing click the desktop link to set the config file to the place it needs to be. The script could both do the copying and removal of both the script and config file from your desktop after it succesfully installed. This method can be used to update the Samba configuration (put your current config in `/etc/skel/`. Put a script in there that has execute permissions and contains a move of said config to `/etc/samba/smbd.conf` and all you need to do afterwards is execute the script).
  - This basically always works since it replaces a post-install manual action with a post-install manually activated script. But it also means it is not part of the custom live cd.

### 3. Cleaning up

```
apt-get clean
rm -rf /tmp/*
rm -f /etc/hosts /etc/resolv.conf
umount /proc/
umount /sys/
exit
```

This removes all the temporary files; not what we created. `~/livecd/` is readonly so a normal `rm` will not remove these files. You need to mount it with write access (or as I did use the new live cd to boot and mount the home and `rm` it from there.

### 4. Setting up the ISO

- Manifest files.

  ```
  chmod +w ~/livecd/cd/casper/filesystem.manifest
  sudo chroot ~/livecd/custom dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} ${Version}\n' > ~/livecd/cd/casper/filesystem.manifest
  sudo cp ~/livecd/cd/casper/filesystem.manifest ~/livecd/cd/casper/filesystem.manifest-desktop
  ```
- Regenerate squashfs file.

  ```
  sudo mksquashfs ~/livecd/custom ~/livecd/cd/casper/filesystem.squashfs
  ```
- Update md5 sums.

  ```
  sudo rm ~/livecd/cd/md5sum.txt
  sudo bash -c 'cd ~/livecd/cd && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +' > md5sum.txt
  ```

### 5. Creating the ISO.

```
cd ~/livecd/cd
sudo mkisofs -r -V "Ubuntu-Live" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -cache-inodes -J -l -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso .
```

### 6. Unmount & Clean

```
sudo umount ~/livecd/squashfs/
sudo umount /tmp/livecd
sudo rm -fr ~/livecd/
```

### 7. Comments:

- Everything was tested with an Ubuntu 11.04 Live CD. Only thing that went wrong was chrooting: I added dchroot to the files you need to install to do this.
- Regarding "should create some firefox shortcuts on desktop", "Should change the default theme to radiance" and "Should change the default ubuntu wallpaper". I edited these in after dv3500ea put it into the comments; I did not test this while creating the 11.04 live cd.

Comment: Will `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` also upgrade the kernel/initrd used on the Live CD? I mean the kernel for the boot process form the live medium, loaded by Syslinux, not the one installed.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` works without a flaw, except for some `warning: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab` messages. Is it supposed to become a problem?

Comment: No. But to be sure have a look at yours and see how / is mounted.

Comment: @Rinzwind I have successfully installed Ubuntu from the customized live cd even in a UEFI system with dual booting. Installed new packages and updated the all packaged along with kernel using `apt-get update` and `upgrade`. Everything went perfect. **EXCEPT** the systems (installed with customized live cd) does not have a `/etc/resolv.conf` (It is to be noted that `/etc/hosts` created as usual). Was it fine to remove `/etc/resolv.conf` in `chmod` environment? Anyway it is not a big deal, I have created a `resolv.conf` using `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Prepare_and_chroot) in 12.04 and 14.04 the `/etc/resolv.conf` may not be removed as a part of the [**cleanup**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Cleanup)

Comment: Thanks you for reporting, @souravc. I have edited chapter `3.-Cleaning Up` in order to fix it.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez you do realize this is about <=11.04 and not 12.04+?

Comment: @Rinzwind This answer is still valid and relevant may be with minor edit, why don't we do so. In the question OP did not mention any particular distribution.

Comment: @souravc there is an answer for each version. That edit should be done in the 12.04 answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/157562/15811  I tested this answer over a period of 3 weeks to make it perfect for version 11.04 and below. I doubt that this alteration is correct for 11.04 but have no longer got the 11.04 install to test this.

Comment: All right, @Rinzwind, I have left things as they were in the beginning, sorry. But I suggest adding some reference like `(*) if [[ -L "/etc/resolv.conf" ]]; then rm -f /etc/hosts; else rm -f /etc/hosts /etc/resolv.conf; fi` or simply `(*) If /etc/resolv.conf is a link instead of a file, don't delete it`. My `if-then` structure was intended to do that: not delete /etc/resolv.conf **case it was a link**, so it should work with **any version**.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I have tested your method (except for the Desktop, gconf-editor and Remote Desktop part) with Ubuntu v14.04.1 LTS (updated later during creation) and Xubuntu v14.02.2 LTS, and they both seem to be working fantastic: installed programs, extra users, locales, internet... etc. Consider updating the title.

Comment: @souravc - Great guide! I am trying to upgrade the xubuntu 15.04 live cd kernel to the latest 4.1-unstable so that I can use it on hitherto unsupported hardware but so far am unable to do it. Followed your guide to the alphabet and installed the required kernel packages using dpkg + removed the stock kernel using apt-get. But when I use the generated ISO, it still reports as using the stock 3.19 kernel (uname -a) - What am I missing?

Comment: @souravc - read somewhere that I need to copy the new kernel and initrd.img to casper folder and did the same.. but still no success...

Here are the details of my entire process - http://pastebin.com/3WG4syS4

Comment: @Praveen May be you have mistaken. Actually [Rinzwind](http://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) wrote this answer not me. Once I had followed the instructions under very special condition. Better you ask the the author. I can also look into the matter. Need some time. You can also ask a new question.

Comment: Asked a new question for this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/641179/how-to-upgrade-the-kernel-of-xubuntu-15-04-live-cd-to-latest-4-1-4-0-6-version

Comment: I am trying to autostart PPTP VPN (package `pptp-linux`). But changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` are not saved. There is any workaround? Just for now I am adding a `pon` command on `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Does this still work in the latest version of ubuntu?  Also does this support EFI computers(like macs)?

Comment: Sure. And efi is not an issue with this.

Comment: This method still works:  Tested with Kubuntu 18.04.2.  note: that I could only make the .ISO bootable using unetbootin (etcher did not work). No problems booting when burning .ISO to a DVD.

Answer (score 23):

### Creating a live CD from an existing/new installation

**EDIT:** This method doesn't seem to work anymore. I suggest you try other methods suggested in this QA.

A good way would be making a live CD from a current installation. This can be done using a virtual machine (just don't install any VM tools inside the guest OS)

So, first we need a fresh install(if you can't install it for real, try using a virtual machine) with only things that you need (in your case thunderbird, samba and ssh). Then we tweak the system and record where the tweaks are (e.g. you change your desktop background, the settings are in ~/.gconf or you add firefox shortcuts, they are located in ~/Desktop). This is needed for step 4.

1. Set up some variables:

   ```
   export WORK=~/temp
   export CD=~/livecd
   export FORMAT=squashfs
   export FS_DIR=casper
   ```

   Replace ~/temp with a path to a temporary
   directory in which we will work in.
   Replace ~/livecd with a path to the
   CD tree.
2. Make the folder structure. `sudo mkdir -p ${CD}/{${FS_DIR},boot/grub} ${WORK}/rootfs`
3. Now we will need to install some packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install grub2 xorriso squashfs-tools
   ```
4. Now we will copy the current installation, modify the exclude flags to fit your needs:

   ```
   sudo rsync -av --one-file-system --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/dev/* \
   --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/home/* --exclude=/lost+found \
   --exclude=/var/tmp/* --exclude=/boot/grub/* --exclude=/root/* \
   --exclude=/var/mail/* --exclude=/var/spool/* --exclude=${WORK}/rootfs \
   --exclude=/etc/fstab --exclude=/etc/mtab --exclude=/etc/hosts \
   --exclude=/etc/timezone --exclude=/etc/shadow* --exclude=/etc/gshadow* \
   --exclude=/etc/X11/xorg.conf* --exclude=/etc/gdm/custom.conf \
   / ${WORK}/rootfs
   ```

   If you have a separate boot partition, execute this: `sudo cp -av /boot/* ${WORK}/rootfs/boot`
   In your case, you want to copy settings and some files from the home directory. First, define what directories we want to copy:
       CONFIG='.config .gconf Desktop someotherfolder andanotherfolder'
   And now we copy that:

   ```
   cd ~ && for i in $CONFIG
   do
   sudo cp -rpv --parents $i ${WORK}/rootfs/etc/skel
   done
   ```
5. Now we chroot into the new system and modify it.

   ```
   sudo mount  --bind /dev/ ${WORK}/rootfs/dev
   sudo mount -t proc proc ${WORK}/rootfs/proc
   sudo mount -t sysfs sysfs ${WORK}/rootfs/sys
   sudo mount -t devpts devpts ${WORK}/rootfs/dev/pts
   sudo chroot ${WORK}/rootfs /bin/bash
   ```

   The next commands are done in chroot:

   ```
   LANG=
   apt-get update
   apt-get install casper
   ```

   Casper contains live scripts.
   If you want an installer too, run this:

   ```
   apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk
   ```

   Or if you want KDE:

   ```
   apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-kde
   ```
6. Update modules.dep and initramfs:

   ```
   depmod -a $(uname -r)
   update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
   ```
7. Remove non-system users - do not worry, we have copied the settings and data into the "skeleton" of users. That means all new users will have them.

   ```
   for i in `cat /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $1}'`
   do
       uid=`cat /etc/passwd | grep "^${i}:" | awk -F":" '{print $3}'`
       [ "$uid" -gt "999" -a  "$uid" -ne "65534"  ] && userdel --force ${i} 2>/dev/null
   done
   ```
8. Clean up:

   ```
   apt-get clean
   find /var/log -regex '.*?[0-9].*?' -exec rm -v {} \;
   find /var/log -type f | while read file
   do
       cat /dev/null | tee $file
   done
   rm /etc/resolv.conf /etc/hostname
   ```
9. Exit chroot. `exit`
10. Now, we copy the kernel:

    ```
    export kversion=`cd ${WORK}/rootfs/boot && ls -1 vmlinuz-* | tail -1 | sed 's@vmlinuz-@@'`
    sudo cp -vp ${WORK}/rootfs/boot/vmlinuz-${kversion} ${CD}/boot/vmlinuz
    sudo cp -vp ${WORK}/rootfs/boot/initrd.img-${kversion} ${CD}/boot/initrd.img
    sudo cp -vp ${WORK}/rootfs/boot/memtest86+.bin ${CD}/boot
    ```
11. If you have installed the installer, you will need to do this, so that the installer doesn't install things like casper:

    ```
    sudo chroot ${WORK}/rootfs dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} ${Version}\n' | sudo tee ${CD}/${FS_DIR}/filesystem.manifest
    sudo cp -v ${CD}/${FS_DIR}/filesystem.manifest{,-desktop}
    REMOVE='ubiquity casper user-setup os-prober libdebian-installer4'
    for i in $REMOVE 
    do
        sudo sed -i "/${i}/d" ${CD}/${FS_DIR}/filesystem.manifest-desktop
    done
    ```
12. Unmount what we have mounted:

    ```
    sudo umount ${WORK}/rootfs/proc
    sudo umount ${WORK}/rootfs/sys
    sudo umount ${WORK}/rootfs/dev/pts
    sudo umount ${WORK}/rootfs/dev
    ```
13. Convert to squashfs:

    ```
    sudo mksquashfs ${WORK}/rootfs ${CD}/${FS_DIR}/filesystem.${FORMAT}
    ```
14. Make filesystem.size:
    `echo -n $(sudo du -s --block-size=1 ${WORK}/rootfs | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}') | sudo tee ${CD}/casper/filesystem.size`
15. And md5: `find ${CD} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sed "s@${CD}@.@" | grep -v md5sum.txt |sudo tee ${CD}/md5sum.txt`
16. Now grub.cfg:

    ```
    sudo nano ${CD}/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    ```

    (replace nano with your fav text editor, it doesn't matter)
    Paste this and save:

    ```
    set default="0"
    set timeout=10

    menuentry "Ubuntu GUI" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }


    menuentry "Ubuntu in safe mode" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper xforcevesa quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }


    menuentry "Ubuntu CLI" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper textonly quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }


    menuentry "Ubuntu GUI persistent mode" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper boot=casper persistent quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }


    menuentry "Ubuntu GUI from RAM" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper nopersistent toram quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }

    menuentry "Check Disk for Defects" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }


    menuentry "Memory Test" {
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
    }


    menuentry "Boot from the first hard disk" {
    set root=(hd0)
    chainloader +1
    }
    ```
17. If you want, you can add an additional menu entry, which allows you to jump straight into Ubiquity.

    ```
    menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash
    initrd /boot/initrd.img
    }
    ```
18. Make the CD/DVD!
        `sudo grub-mkrescue -o ~/live-cd.iso ${CD}`
19. Test it using a virtual machine!

**All credit goes to capink, because the guide is from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872).**

Comment: I have a question about the grub.cfg.
Is this file grub.cfg just used while installation, or is it persistent to the installed system also.
What if I dont edit the grub.cfg ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge This configures GRUB on the CD. It shouldn't persist after installation.

Comment: Can we just have the installation like how it is for Ubuntu normally, that is, show the ubiquity installer, rather than showing grub?

Means, in Ubuntu installation, when we insert and run the cd, ubiquity shows up rather than grub menu, Can we do like that ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge It should be possible by adding a menu entry with `linux /boot/vmlinuz boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash`. I will test and verify.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge I have successfully added an option to launch Ubiquity from the boot menu. However, I need to fix the guide - some ubiquity steps are missing. I will attempt to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you Nick for the fast response. I am hopefully waiting for this.
Is the "edits" you mentioned above refers to installing Ubiquity and all ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge Looks like I did something wrong yesterday. I didn't need to edit anything this time. I have added a step for your convenience.

Comment: Still a grub menu is shown. Is it possible to skip that..
And when I select ubuntu gui, it shows the lighdm login screen and ask for a username and password. what should i give there.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge I tried fixing this, but without success. I got to the point where logging in works but not really - the system doesn't create a temporary user. I am going to mark this method as "not working" for now, considering that there are better methods that achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`uck`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/) or the `live-magic` to customize your Live CD.

`uck` is available from Ubuntu's official software sources, in all versions of Ubuntu since 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx. You can install `uck` from the Software Center, with `apt-get` on the command-line, or by [clicking here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=uck) [image: Install uck].

Comment: looks like UCK has been discontinued :(

Comment: Ubuntu Builder was discontinued in 2014; Ubuntu Customization Kit installs but doesn't work and was discontinued in 2015; System Imager was discontinued in 2016. This answer really needs to be updated. Is there an offiically supported method in 2019?

Comment: @allquixotic `uck`  is in the 18.04 universe repository. Does this version not work?

Answer (score 10):

[Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net)

It is a collection of scripts that make it easier to create a custom LiveCD from an existing .iso image. It is very similar to Remastersys, with the difference that it is actively maintained. It has a GUI to help with the customization, but one can also use the command-line to do the same.

1. It will ask to select which language packs to include in the CD.
2. Then, it will ask to select the .iso image file, which will be used as the base for the new CD.
3. Give a name for the new .iso image that will be created.
4. Then, it will ask for the packages that are to be added/removed to/from the LiveCD. It will give you an option between the command-line and the default GUI (Ubuntu Software Center). Note: You should select command-line. From the command-line, you can add/remove packages either using apt-get or using Ubuntu Software Center (type software-center from the command-line). You can also modify configuration settings for all the software/apps.
5. After you have finished (it might take some time to download the required packages), continue.
6. Now, just sit back and relax. After some time, your customized LiveCD will be ready.

Comment: looks like the UCK project has been discontinued :(

Answer (score 8):

### Duplicating a Ubuntu System for Distribution

None of the current answers on this page still work. At least not with Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10. All of the apps have been abandoned. Using an image file to duplicate an OS is simple and will always work.

**1) Create Image file from existing operating system.**

- Boot Live Ubuntu USB and insert Full install, (or Persistent), USB to be copied.
- Create an image file of the Full install USB, (or Persistent USB), using GNOME Disks.

  [image: GNOME Disks]

  [image: Create disk image dialog]

**2) Truncate image for distribution, remove unwanted space from end of image file.**

**Example:** Remove NTFS Microsoft basic data partition from end of drive.

Input:

```
cd /media/ubuntu/DATA/
fdisk -l DiskImageofsdd.img
```

Output:

```
Disk DiskImageofsdd.img: 28.66 GiB, 30752636928 bytes, 60063744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 82741D01-6511-4A8A-8FDF-52D8C165C178

Device                 Start      End  Sectors   Size Type
DiskImageofsdd.img1     1953     3906     1954   977K BIOS boot
DiskImageofsdd.img2     3907   503906   500000 244.1M EFI System
DiskImageofsdd.img3   505856 44578815 44072960    21G Linux filesystem
DiskImageofsdd.img4 44578816 60061695 15482880   7.4G Microsoft basic data
```

Input:

```
truncate --size=$[(44578815+1)*512] DiskImageofsdd.img
```

**3) Compress image for distribution.**

- For xz compression, if you are on Windows install [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) from https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.msi, or, if you are on Ubuntu install [P7Zip](https://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) from the Ubuntu store. Once 7-Zip has been installed on Windows or Ubuntu, the flashing tool should work without first decompressing the xz file.
- PKZip compression may also be used but is not as tight.

**4) Virtual Machine: Convert `.vdi` file to `.img` file that can be flashed to bootable USB.**

- Open VirtualBox.
- `cd` to folder that contains `ubuntu.vdi` and run:

  ```
  VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img
  ```

**5) Install Image File to target drive.**

**Caution: The target drive will be overwritten.**

- Use the pancake icon in Disks or use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) or [`mkusb`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) when you want to restore or clone the image to another drive.

**6) Create Installer Drive for Image File.**

- Use Etcher, Startup Disk Creator, `dd`, `mkusb`, etc to make a Live USB.
- From another Linux drive, convert the new writable partition to NTFS partition using:

  ```
  sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L usbdata /dev/sdx
  ```

  where `sdx` is the Live drive.
- Place the OS image file in the NTFS partition of the Live USB, where it can be flashed to a target drive from the Live USB when required.

Comment: Only valid answer for 20.04+ 

Comment: I am confused at some parts: (1) Does "Boot Live Ubuntu USB and insert Full install, (or Persistent), USB to be copied." mean that I need to do everything in a live boot on a real machine (based on the disks shown in the photo), or can I do that in a VM (based on step 4)? Or are they multiple options in one step? I assume I should customize everything before step 1 anyway.

Comment: @MakisH: This was written to duplicate a Persistent or Full install USB, (as an alternative to Remastersys and other methods that no longer work). It should also work for duplicating Ubuntu installed on hard drive, however, the larger the drive being duplicated the longer it takes and the larger the disk required to save it. It should also work when booted to Ubuntu from the hard drive or from VM, (I have not tried this booted from VM). Step 4 is used to convert a .vdi file to a .img file in case you wish to duplicate Ubuntu located on a VM file and not a physical drive.

Answer (score 7):

If you need more control over exactly what changes are made, it is possible to make the modification manually.

The process consists of unpacking the [SquashFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) data file containing the live OS's root filesystem, [chrooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into the extracted filesystem, making your modifications, exiting the chroot, repacking the SquashFS file, and then regenerating the ISO image.

Complete details are described on the [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) page of the Ubuntu wiki.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic) -- this utility has been tested (by me) and works on Ubuntu 18.04 host with an Ubuntu 18.04 image, which is more than can be said for most of the other tools that don't work or are discontinued.

Here is a guide to use it from the website [Linoxide](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/create-custom-live-cd-image-cubic-ubuntu/).

The rough steps involve:

- Make sure you're using a supported version of Ubuntu (I tried 18.04; it works)
- Install the GPG key for the Cubic PPA
- Add the Cubic PPA to your sources
- Install the cubic tool
- Run it, and follow the GUI prompts

Comment: Also, see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/100356 for instructions.

Comment: Because of this answer I gave Cubic a try with 20.04 and unlike most answers on this page it worked as advertised, thank you.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me in 2023, creating a custom Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB. Very easy, the documentation and the interface are very easy to follow, and the maintainer very responsive. Definitely worth supporting this project!

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu Software Center

> **Edit>Software Sources>Other Software>Add..**

Paste the following line in the box and click add source.

> deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic

Reload the sources and install Remastersys from Software Center.

Once done, install all the media codecs and apps you'd like on your custom ubuntu.
Start remastersys from

> **System>Adminstration>Remastersys**

Pick **dist** mode, click ok and Wait for the process to finish. Once done, you'll find your custom iso in

> **/home/remastersys/remastersys/custom.iso**

Comment: I've followed exact the same procedures as you described here, but unfortunately during boot it's showing "could not find ramdisk image: /ubninit" and get refreshed again and again with 10 seconds interval. Result: I can't boot my customized ISO. Could you tell me how can I solve this? Please.

Answer (score 3):

Remastersys could be the answer to your needs. You need to go to http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html and follow the instructions. This program makes an iso from your running os including all settings and apps. Than you can burn a CD using this iso. Unfortunately, there was in the past an issue to get it running as a live cd, while installing was no problem (I dont know if this is still a problem).

Comment: or UCK which uses GUI and is less difficult

Comment: Remastersys is dead. Now this site is owned by a domain squatter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "GUI" that I know of outside of Lucid, however [gNewsense](http://www.gnewsense.org/), which is a fork of Ubuntu makes [their scripts](http://www.gnewsense.org/Builder/Builder) to take an Ubuntu release and make a custom fork freely available and rather well documented.

Its basically a process of:

1. Placing your custom artwork where the scripts can find it
2. Deciding what you want in your kernel (or what you don't want)
3. Deciding what packages you want (or what you don't want)
4. Running a script that mirrors an apt repository
5. Creating the distribution CD / ISO.

While not exactly 'novice friendly', their tools are relatively easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have tinkered with a new web-based service called [Reconstructor](https://build.reconstructor.org/). According to their website,

> Reconstructor  is a toolkit for
>   creating custom versions of the
>   GNU/Linux operating system,
>   specifically Debian  and Ubuntu.

According to a [Linux Journal article about Reconstructor](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/howto-customized-live-dvds-reconstructors-web-ui), they charge small fees for customizations. Whether it's worth it depends on your needs.

Comment: link is dead and domain redirects to potentially malicious site!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to try [Reconstructor](http://build.reconstructor.org/)

"Reconstructor is an Ubuntu GNU/Linux CD Creator that allows you to modify an existing Ubuntu distribution and save as your own Linux distribution. It uses the Desktop(Live), Alternate(Install), or Server disc as a base, and then allows for user customization.
You can basically customize the entire environment, such as add/remove software, change the default look (splash, themes, fonts, wallpaper, etc.), add desktop links, etc."

Also for more info you should read these links: http://maketecheasier.com/reconstructor-creating-your-own-ubuntu-distribution/2008/07/05

http://maketecheasier.com/build-your-own-ubuntu-based-distro-with-novo-builder/2010/07/02

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869659

Comment: But these tools wont let me rebrand my distro, they will only allow me to build images and add packages, or atleast that's what I know.

Comment: reconstructor link is dead and domain redirects to potentially malicious site!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JLIVECD](https://github.com/neurobin/JLIVECD) too to customize a ISO image. It's a command line tool to customize Ubuntu and Ubuntu based distros. It gives you complete control over things that needs customization but you need to know what needs to be done i.e it only prepares the chroot environment for you (the rest is upto you) and builds the final ISO. You can keep adding new changes to the existing changes and keep checking the ISOs built on them.

Answer (score 0):

Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/files/uck/2.4.6/uck_2.4.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb/download
follow the instructions and when it asks to run package manager, a console application or continue packing, select Console application.

Now you can run

> nautilus
>
> unity-2d-launcher
>
> unity-2d-panel

and do everything.

If this doesn't work first try running the package manager, then try again with the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ubuntu customization kit (UCK) has been discontinued

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default `/etc/hosts` file (as well as some other default files) by editing `/usr/share/ubiquity/plugininstall.py`

I thought it would be helpful to share as I needed to know how to do this.

Comment: Actually after further review it appears the `/etc/hosts` file that gets installed is not generated by the ubiquity `plugininstall.py` module.

If you do wish to modify the default `/etc/hosts` file you will likely have to make a script that will run once after first boot and delete or rename itself. Unless you recompile the netcfg module - which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, and most of the answers are (naturally?) outdated. I'd like to share my solution:

1. Install Ubuntu 18.04 to e.g. Virtualbox VM.
2. Customize to your needs: install new software, etc.
3. Download `pinguybuilder_5.2-1_all.deb` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/ and install it. ***NB**: Pinguybuilder is an abandonded project, but it did do what I needed.*
4. Run `sudo PinguyBuilder backup` (or `sudo PinguyBuilder dist`, see below) - this can take an hour!
5. Find the ISO file in `/home/PinguyBuilder/PinguyBuilder/custom-backup.iso` and copy it to a USB stick with something like `sudo dd if=/home/PinguyBuilder/PinguyBuilder/custom-backup.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M` (where `sdX` is the USB stick device)

### Choosing the mode ([source](https://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/))

> Depending on what option you choose determines what type of ISO gets created.
> If you pick “Dist”, this will backup the whole system but exclude your home folder and any personal info.

> If you pick “Backup”, this will backup the system and will include you home folder (so make sure it isn’t to big).

> Both options can run as a live session. “Dist” mode has no password to login. “Backup” mode uses the user name and password used to create the ISO.

Comment: pinguybuilder was abandoned three years ago.

Comment: Thanks @C.S.Cameron - I added a note.

Comment: As far as I know Cameron's answer is the only answer on this page that is currently up-to-date. Cameron maintains his content, but it's not going to do anyone much good unless his answer gets 117 more upvotes that would put it at the top of this page where users will see it and read it.